# Use code to find another translation of a DNN page to link to the correct language

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7, 2sxc

i have a list view with a link to the detail view with 2sexycontent.
at the list view i created a tag for the link with href="@Content.Link" 
this works for german, but at the other 4 languages i have a problem with the localization. cause the tabs have differet links and at the moment all the details links get redirected to the german detail view.

how can i find the link to the corresponding DNN page with the other language using the standard DNN API?

thanks

regards

michael

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

1. in the entity translations, specify the other page (probably not sexy)
2. look up the dnn-page which is the translated one of the page you have

I believe you want to do #2. I don't have the code snippet for that at hand, but it should be easy to find it in google or stack-overflow. Just ask for "How to find a translated page in server code" or something like that. Would be great if you share the result.